# Problems with php install on centos server

Tags: php, centos

I'm having trouble with my php, at first I couldn't get /usr/bin/php to version above 7. When I do php -v in my root it said the version was above 7 but when I did phpunit command it said /usr/bin was v5, and needed to be higher like v7.

After doing some things, PHP disappeared in usr/bin and I want to know how I can reinstall PHP and then in 1 go do the good version.

Somebody can help me?

Comment: This might be better suited for the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) stack exchange. (Given that this deals with the operations-side of things.) Regardless, please provide more information, Vano, as saying, "After doing some things,..." doesn't really give readers a good idea of your machine's current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `yum -y remove php*` to remove all php versions at once.

Then you install your preferred version 7 or above 7 and this [link](https://www.tecmint.com/install-php-7-in-centos-7/) may help you.

Then you need to restart your server (whatever server you have... apache or nginx or any); then `php -v` to check your php version.

Hope the above piece of information may help you out.

Comment: I thank you a hel of a lot! Nowhere could I find this answer thanks!